# Can an upper forearm amputee correctly control the Median and Ulnar nerves

Tags: human-anatomy, neuroanatomy, neurophysiology

I'm an engineer who is looking to build a robotic hand for people without their upper forearm(from center of forearm in direction of hand), controlled by the [Thalmic Myo](https://www.thalmic.com/en/myo/)(an EMG sensor). I am first checking for the idea's viability.

I was wondering if one who does not have their upper forearm can still send the correct nerve impulses for a desired hand movement through their Median and Ulnar nerves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, severed nerves still convey neural responses from the brain**.

In fact, nerve potential recordings in the ulnar and median nerves of the stumps of arm amputees have already been successfully applied to control arm prosthetics (Jia et al. 2007; Kuiken et al., 2007.

Comment: I will work on formatting the refs later. I am mobile. Kuiken et al.: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17276777. Jia et.al: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17482005

Comment: Will such patients have phantom arm syndrome? @ChrisStronks?

Comment: @CRags - likely. Many amputees have phantom sensations, but I am not an expert on that. I am only familiar with Ramachandran's work and that suggests it is very common in upper arm amputees. The severity differs.

Comment: I am asking particularly about people with prosthesis as they need ulnar, radial and median nerves in functional order. If you find anything incidentally anytime please add it with a comment to me! Thanks!

Comment: @CRags - For now I can say that active use of (conventional) prosthetics reduces phantom pain. I will update if I find out more.